# Symplectic structure moduli of simple bundles on hyper-Kaehler manifolds

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, moduli-spaces, holomorphic-symplectic

Let $S$ be a K3 or Abelian surface and let $M_{S}$ be a moduli of stable bundles on $S$. Then, Mukai proves that there $M_{S}^{H}$ has a symplectic structure. Indeed, let $\mathcal{F}$ be the universal bundle on $S \times M_{S}^{H}$. Then, by Serre duality, we have a perfect skew symmetric pairing:

$$ R^1 p_* \mathcal{H}om(\mathcal{F}, \mathcal{F}) \times R^1 p_* \mathcal{H}om(\mathcal{F}, \mathcal{F}) \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{M_S^H},$$

where $p : S \times M_S^H \rightarrow M_{S}$ is the canonical projection. As $R^1 p_* \mathcal{H}om( \mathcal{F}, \mathcal{F})$ is the tangent bundle of $M_S$, the above mentionned pairing gives a symplectic form on $M_S$. (one should also prove that this two form is closed but this is a bit more technical and not relevant to my question).

It seems that Kobayashi extended Mukai's result in there : https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pja/1195514493. He proves that if $X$ is a hyper-Kaehler manifold and $M_X$ is a moduli of simple vector bundles on $X$, then $M_X$ is endowed with a symplectic form.

The proof of Kobayashi is very differentialo geometric in nature and I know almost nothig about moduli of complex structures on $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}$ bundles. I'd like to know if an "elementary" algebraic proof of Kobayashi's result is known, using like similar ideas as Mukai did?

Thanks a lot!